# query joining two tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

There are my tables:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlIWx.png

I want to write a query that return all info order by `categoryId` and `Name`.

For example: I want to return from right table id = 2,15,18 (CategoryId=1)
because in the left table they belong to Java (Id=1)

Comment: use join and order by categoryID,Name

Comment: you can write this please?

Comment: instead of posting an image link to your problem, insert the actual data in the question **[like so](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30103455/t-sql-merging-data)**. It's not hard to copy and paste it with some formatting. if that link dies or is inaccessible for some reason, the data is still going to be visible if it's in the post.

Comment: @MaorAzulay that's not really ok, as you have your answer, but in the future, other users may look at this and it isn't going to be of any use if they can't see the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help to solve the problem:

```
select * 
from mytable1 
join mytable2 on mytable1.ID=mytable2.CategoryID 
order by mytable1.ID ,Name
```