# T-SQL Merging data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge

I've imported data from an `XML` file by using SSIS to SQL Server.
The result what I got in the database is similar to this:

```
+-------+---------+---------+-------+
|  ID   |  Name   |  Brand  | Price |
+-------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2     | NULL    | NULL    | 100   |
| NULL  | SLX     | NULL    | NULL  |
| NULL  | NULL    | Blah    | NULL  |
| NULL  | NULL    | NULL    | 100   |
+-------+---------+---------+-------+
```

My desired result would be:

```
+-------+---------+---------+-------+
|  ID   |  Name   |  Brand  | Price |
+-------+---------+---------+-------+
| 2     | SLX     | Blah    | 100   |
+-------+---------+---------+-------+
```

Is there a pretty solution to solve this in T-SQL?
I've already tried it with a `SELECT MAX(ID)` and then a `GROUP BY ID`, but I'm still stuck with the `NULL` values. Also I've tried it with `MERGE`, but also a failure.
Could someone give me a direction where to search further?

Comment: You could select MAX on all columns.   With no GROUP BY at all.

Comment: I'm assuming this is not the only 4 rows in the table(that should be 1 row). I would first recommend you go to the SSIS and adjust that. If you cannot well, there is nothing that really ties these values together, so it's not possible until you relate them in some way. The only way I could think of is you have an extra like row_number INT IDENTITY(1,1) column. If I had that, I could write you a solution.

Comment: If you cannot resolve the issue at the import step then I would recommend transforming the data with the solution @JohnnyBell provided before storing it in a permanent table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select `MAX` on all columns....

```
SELECT MAX(ID), MAX(NAME), MAX(BRAND), MAX(PRICE)
FROM [TABLE]
```

**[Click here for a fiddley fidd fiddle...](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6d849/2)**